# Using np.where for nested lists

Tags: python, numpy, nested

I am trying to use np.where() function with nested lists.
I would like to find an index with a given condition of the first layer of the nested list.

For example, if I have the following code

```
arr = [[1,1], [2,2],[3,3]]
a = np.where(arr == [2,2])
```

then ideally I would like code to return 'a' as 1.
Since [2,2] is in index 1 of the nested list.

However, I am just getting a empty array back as a result.

Of course, I can make it work easily by implementing external for loop such as

```
for n in range(len(arr)):
   if arr[n] == [2,2]:
      a = n
```

but I would like to implement this simply within the function np.where(write the entire code here).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `where` is only as good as the condition array.  Look at `arr == [2,2]` or other attempts.

Comment: `arr.index([2,2])` ?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny would `index` find all indices with value of `[2, 2]`?

Comment: @MSH - No, only the first index, ValueError if it's not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is that mentioned by @Michael Szczesny, but using `np.where` you can do this too:

```
a = np.where(np.array(arr) == [2, 2])[0]
resulted_ind = np.where(np.bincount(a) == 2)[0]  # --> [1]
```

Comment: thanks. I see. I actually did not know that "index" existed in Python...fresh user from MATLAB.

Comment: `index` is a method of a list (basic Python).  Your `arr` is a list (despite the name).  A numpy array, which is more like the MATLAB matrix, does not have the equivalent `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write your own function to do so:

You'll need to

- Find every line equal to what you looking for
- Get indices of found rows (You can use `where`):

### `numpy` compression

You can use compression operator to see if each line satisfies the condition. Such as:

```
np_arr = np.array(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
)
print(np_arr < 3)
```

This will return a boolean where every element is `True` or `False` where the condition is satisfied:

```
[ True  True False False False]
```

For a 2D array you'll get a 2D boolean array:

```
to_find = np.array([2, 2])
np_arr = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [2, 2]
    ]
)
print(np_arr == to_find)
```

The result is:

```
[[False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]]
```

Now we are looking for lines with `all` `True` values. So we can use `all` method of `ndarray`. And we will provide the axis we are looking to look to all. X, Y or Both. We want to look to x axis:

```
to_find = np.array([2, 2])
np_arr = np.array(
    [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [2, 2]
    ]
)
print((np_arr == to_find).all(axis=1))
```

The result is:

```
[False  True False  True]
```

### Get indices of `True`s

At the end you are looking for indices where the values are `True`:

```
np.where((np_arr == to_find).all(axis=1))
```

The result would be:

```
(array([1, 3]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` runs in Python, so you can use both the basic Python lists and `numpy` arrays (which are more like MATLAB matrices)

A list of lists:

```
In [43]: alist = [[1,1], [2,2],[3,3]]
```

A list has an `index` method, which tests against each element of the list (elements here are 2 element lists):

```
In [44]: alist.index([2,2])
Out[44]: 1
In [45]: alist.index([2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [45] in <cell line: 1>
    alist.index([2,3])
ValueError: [2, 3] is not in list
```

`alist==[2,2]` returns `False`, because the list is not the same as the `[2,2]` list.

If we make an array from that list:

```
In [46]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [47]: arr
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

we can do an `==` test - but it compares numeric elements.

```
In [48]: arr == np.array([2,2])
Out[48]: 
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

Underlying this comparison is the concept of `broadcasting`, allow it to compare a (3,2) array with a (2,)  (a 2d with a 1d).  Here's its trivial, but it can be much more complicated.

To find rows where all values are True, use:

```
In [50]: (arr == np.array([2,2])).all(axis=1)
Out[50]: array([False,  True, False])
```

and `where` finds the `True` in that array (the result is a tuple with 1 array):

```
In [51]: np.where(_)
Out[51]: (array([1]),)
```

In Octave the equivalent is:

```
>> arr = [[1,1];[2,2];[3,3]]
arr =

   1   1
   2   2
   3   3

>> all(arr == [2,2],2)
ans =

  0
  1
  0
>> find(all(arr == [2,2],2))
ans =  2
```